# Keep UIView while animating navController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview, segue, pushviewcontroller

How can I animate in a new uinavigation controller but keep the same uiview in the window?

I've seen this done in the opposite - a navController stay in place while a container view changes a view controller as a child view controller, but I want the opposite:a main view, a mapview, to remain in the window at all times while a new vc2 slides in from a push segue which will show a different navBar title and uibarbutton items. This is important because I need the mapview from VC1 to replicate in VC2, or to that effect.

Can this be done and how? Thank you for suggestions all,

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Does vc2 need to have that same map view (the same instance)? If so, why are you switching to a new vc? What is the purpose of having two view controllers if they control the same view?

Comment: Yes you're correct, the point is that the user in vc! is adding annotations to the map and there are lots of UI elements involved, and then in vc2 the map then gets other elements added like google places API and overlay renderings. Is that not a sensible thing to do?

Comment: It's hard to say in the abstract whether it makes sense or not. It's not a usual situation to have two different view controllers controlling the same view.

Comment: I know, I keep runnning into difficulty with this. What I'll probably settle for is creating the illusion that the mapview in vc1 didn't move/animate in with vc2 whilst the other elements like the navigationBar will move in, but then again this is also proving troublesome at the moment because of removing mapview from vc1 and sending it to vc2 before vc2 animates in.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be better to do this without a navigation controller. You can create a custom container controller with a navigation bar at the top. You can add vc2 as a child of your container controller, remove the map view from vc1, add it to the view of vc2, and remove vc1 from the container controller. This would all be done with no animation, so the user shouldn't see anything happening in the main view. You can call pushNavigationItem:animated: on the navigation bar to animate in the new navigation item.